# NS-2.31 Make fail while adding a transport layer protocol

Tags: compiling, make, ns2

While adding a transport layer protocol in ns-2.31 in ubuntu 14.04, I am coming across the following error that I have been unable to resolve.

"make: *** [dtsncc/dtsncc-cache.o] Error 1" (screenshot available at)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8aoxw4cxra1o9v/dtsn%20error%20capture.png?dl=0

I have followed the instructions written in the readme file. I have ns2.31 working + fixRT + ns2measureDCF. I have modified the following files before the 'make'.

- Packet.h
- cmu-trace.cc and cmu-trace.h
- priqueue.cc
- ns-default.tcl
- ns-packet.tcl
- Makefile

A copy of the above mentioned files along with the compiler version are available at
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8mc9nyimljat42k/AAA4fBEkEEu7DyhGGxSd_9y3a?dl=0

Still I'm coming across the error in the attachment. The output of the make command can be seen at:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kambh7ns7d6i1c/make%20error?dl=0

The code for the protocol is available at
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ngygz5nuxl0885/AAA3u1vnKIk9wZRf65GupUvCa?dl=0

I would really appreciate if someone can help me ASAP. I dont have alot of time to spare and have been trying to resolve this issue for the last 7 days. Also, all the contents of the above link can be found at

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3kwtmmklytyp438/AAC5CkoYB55zfE0kpIyrQO1ka?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your post to include Ubuntu version. .... Compiling with g++34 ( export CXX=g++34 && ./configure && make ), I get : `dtsncc/dtsncc-cache.h:8:31: ndtsn/ndtsn-cache.h: No such file or directory` .... What are those files in ndtsn/ ? .... P.S. : Images with text are not appreciated.  Please replace with text.

Comment: I have made the necessary modifications in the question. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Another missing file, **fixtb.h** : `fixrt/fixrt.h:22:19: fatal error: fixtb.h: No such file or directory` ... Actually I get no errors, except for the missing file, even with g++ version 4.9.2 . ... EDIT : found it http://m.blog.csdn.net/article/details?id=9241245

Comment: `fixrt.cc` : How about these → `#include <dtsn/dtsn-pkt.h>` ,  `#include <rmst/rmst.h>` , `#include <dtpa/dtpa.h>` ?

Comment: The files you've asked for are available at

dtsn-pkt.h(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nbnpexa9laf7044/AACt7ENh2RphtrywtlGDwkSba?dl=0),
rmst.h(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1yrszqtw57nptk6/AADEShcqClNVzOIr-mGMHQQha?dl=0) 
dtpa.h(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dw1w70vzsaiertm/AAALJlpm7lneJHg74WfFa0tYa?dl=0)
fixRT(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7vyeouiul7n5qel/AACqAu45Y8Pl_VZdSq9wHwGma?dl=0). The instructions that I was following  are at (https://github.com/nctsim/dtsncc).

Answer (score 0):

Your "error output" shows warnings, no errors.

Depending on the object order in the `Makefile.in`, I get two different errors. The readable results are here, dtsncc_14.Jul.2016_errors.txt https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZFlraEZXQWdCaGM/view?usp=sharing

```
fixrt/fixrt.cc:850: error: ‘HDR_NDTSN’ was not declared in this scope
```

Edit **01** : I created a patch with all the changes, including `ns231_gcc44.patch`,  `ns2measure-2.31-070909.patch` : **dtsncc-all_ns231-01.patch** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZzdzNGFBQXBTcW8/view?usp=sharing

Please try with the Ubuntu g++-4.4 compiler: `export CXX=g++-4.4 && ./configure && make`

.... The patch `ns231_gcc44.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUy1ldnhCeUlEUHc/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 2 : The error output with Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNdmRiVGFsSlBBYnM/view?usp=sharing

---

EDIT 3, 26Jul : Got your "ns-2.31dtsncc". Replaced the header `dtsncc/dtsncc.h` with this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNMUpGUWx2STF0M0k/view?usp=sharing , and got some further with 'make'. Which leaves us with this error :
`wnd_' was not declared in this scope` →

```
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc: In constructor `NDtsnAgent::NDtsnAgent()':
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc:48: error: `wnd_' was not declared in this scope
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc: In member function `char* NDtsnAgent::get_bitmap_string(int*)':
.
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc: In member function `virtual int NDtsnAgent::window()':
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc:573: error: `wnd_' was not declared in this scope
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc: In member function `virtual double NDtsnAgent::windowd()':
ndtsn/ndtsn.cc:578: error: `wnd_' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: The error at
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZFlraEZXQWdCaGM/view)

dtsncc/dtsncc.cc:690: error: ‘class AODV’ has no member named ‘get_num_hops’

I was able to resolve it by adding the following in aodv.h file:

At location

class AODV: public Tap, public Agent {

  /*
   * make some friends first 
   */

        friend class aodv_rt_entry;
        .
        .  .
        .
 public:
        AODV(nsaddr_t id);

        void  recv(Packet *p, Handler *);
  void tap(const Packet *p);
  int  get_num_hops(nsaddr_t node_id, nsaddr_t dst);

Comment: I have not been very fortunate with

fixrt/fixrt.cc:850:29: error: ‘HDR_NDTSN’ was not declared in this scope
  hdr_ndtsn *th = HDR_NDTSN(p);

Comment: I was given this folder by my advisor and he has asked me to add it to ns-2. The folder is at:
[folder](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmmp0dj6pxgapeb/ns-2.31dtsncc.tar.gz?dl=0)


The error that I am is as follow:

queue/priqueue.cc: In member function ‘virtual void PriQueue::recv(Packet*, Handler*)’:
queue/priqueue.cc:98:19: warning: unused variable ‘dtpah’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct hdr_dtpa *dtpah = HDR_DTPA(p);
                   ^
make: *** [queue/priqueue.o] Error 1


Details can be seen at

[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ugb6o0kkbsnmpg/error.txt?dl=0)


Please help.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, EDIT 3,  26 July 2016.

Comment: So all I need to do is replace dtsncc/dtsncc.h with the dtsncc.h that you have replaced and do make clean followed by make right?